# js pass object to callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to reference the item object in the geocoder callback function.
Item always refers to the state of the last $each iteration, if I use the code below. I assume this is because the callback is run after the $each loop finishes. I would therefore need to pass the item object to the geocoder. How can I do that?

```
 $.each(results.data, function(index) {
        var item = results.data[index];
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            item.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            item.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        });
    });
```

Comment: The way you are doing it should work fine. What makes you think it always points to the last item? You never test its value in the code you've shared. You need to provide a real test case: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Wild speculation: When you created `results.data` you put multiple copies of the reference to the *same* object in the array.

Comment: The variable `results` never changes here and you are always picking up the first element so i guess the result should always be the first element?

Comment: Unless your `geocode` returns different `results` for the same `address` or you somehow modify `address` through each iteration. i'd assume it's on a higher scope since it isn't declared anywhere on the function.

Comment: @MinusFour results does change as it is always a different object provided by the geocoders callback function. (i.e. geocode is run multiple times and returns a different results object each time.) It is probably confusing since the callback results is not the same as the results used for the each iterator

Comment: @Quentin The data array contains different elements which I could confirm with a console.log

Comment: Yes, `results` is a different object each time but are you sure they aren't the same `results`? I mean, if you run multiple times a query for a specific `address` that doesn't change, shouldn't you get the same results?

Comment: @Chris — You still need to provide a [real test case](http://sscce.org/). Providing vague descriptions of what the data is like and vague descriptions of what result you expect isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't entirely understand the question, so maybe this won't help but are you trying to do something like:

```
results.data.forEach(function(item) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        item.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        item.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    });
});
```

This will make sure the reference to item is correct. If it's an object you could use Lodash's forOwn instead of forEach. If you really want to use jQuery then the second parameter of the callback would be item.